# FFMPEG Webcam YouTube stream configuration

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, webcam, youtube

I was hoping someone could take a look at this code and offer suggestions.

BACKGROUND: I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 & Logitech 1080p/30fps webcam to stream directly to YouTube.

ISSUE:  No matter how much I play around with these settings, the output seems to be "stuck" at about 10-15 fps.

- "-c:v libx264" vs "-c:v h264_v4l2m2m" were the same
- tried several different "-preset" values
- it doesn't appear to be a network latency issue.  Stream is consistent

*v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-fmt-video=width=1280,height=720 ; ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 1024 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=16000:cl=mono -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v h264_v4l2m2m -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -g 60 -b:v 4M -c:a aac -ar 44100 -bufsize 8M -maxrate 4M -filter:v fps=30 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/"KEY"*

Thanks for the help!